# Expectation and Variance of location scale exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

Let's suppose we have the following location scale exponential distribution:

$P(X>x)={ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }$

We are looking to determine $E(X)$ and $V(X)$

There are several ways to do it, but I'm looking at the fastest way to solve it.

What I've done:

I'm trying the get the density:

$F(x)=1-P(X>x)=1-{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }$

So, by derivation, $f(x)=C{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }$

From there, can we just say the following things : ???

$f(x)={ e }^{ C({ x }_{ 0 }) }\times C{ e }^{ -Cx }$

and since $C{ e }^{ -Cx }$ is just an exponential with parameter $C$, therefore with expectation $1/C$.

So $E(X)=\frac { { e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } } }{ C } $ and $V(X)=\frac { { e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } } }{ { C }^{ 2 } } $

Is it correct to formulate things that way ?

Thanks for your feedback.

---

Added :

By following another approach (the Gamma approach), I'm finding something weird:

$E(X)=\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ Cx{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }{ 1 }_{ x>{ x }_{ 0 } } } dx=C{ e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } }\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ x{ e }^{ -Cx }{ 1 }_{ x>0 } } dx=C{ e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } }\frac { 1! }{ { C }^{ 2 } } \int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ \frac { { C }^{ 2 } }{ 1! } x{ e }^{ -Cx }{ 1 }_{ x>0 } } dx=\frac { { e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } } }{ C } $

Why do I get this wrong result ?

Comment: $f(x)={ e }^{ -C({ x }_{ 0 }) }\times C{ e }^{ +Cx }$

Comment: Actually the PDF (if one insists on using it, which is neither necessary nor the most direct way) is  $f(x)=Ce^{-C(x-x_0)}\mathbf 1_{x\gt x_0}$, not  $f(x)=Ce^{-C(x-x_0)}$. Using this could make your problem evaporate.

Comment: Thanks Did your giving me guidance, I will try using your trick and then edit my post.

Comment: Well Did: I supposed that's what you meant: $f(x)=\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ C{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }{ 1 }_{ x>{ x }_{ 0 } } } dx=\int _{ { x }_{ 0 } }^{ +\infty  }{ C{ e }^{ -Cx }dx } $ ?. I suppose that from here, I am supposed to compute $xf(x)$ and then $x^2 f(x)$ ?

Comment: Another question for you Did: what's the most direct way if it's not getting the pdf ?

Comment: No, I just meant what I wrote: $$f(x)=Ce ^{-C(x-x_0)}\,\mathbf 1_{x\gt x_0}.$$

Comment: Allright. But, doing the computation of $E(X)$ and $V(X)$ from there seems quite lengthy. You told there is a more direct way. What did you mean please ? Is the change of variable the only other option ? Moreover, what do you think about my gamma approach (added to my post above) which does not yield the correct result ?

Comment: Direct way: see @heropup's answer. (Unrelated: please use `@`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just standardize the variable, calculate its moments, then transform back:  e.g., let $Y = g(X) = C(X-x_0)$, then $X = g^{-1}(Y) = Y/C + x_0$, where $Y \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$.  So $$\operatorname{E}[Y^k] = \int_{y=0}^\infty y^k e^{-y} \, dy = k!, \quad k = 1, 2, \ldots,$$ and it follows that $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = 2 - 1 = 1,$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[X] = 1/C + x_0, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X] = 1/C^2.$$

---

If you want to do the calculation using indicator functions, then you need to be mindful of the relationship between the indicator function and the interval of integration:  that is to say, if your density is $$f_X(x) = Ce^{-C(x-x_0)} \mathbb 1(x > x_0),$$ then $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^k f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty C x^k e^{-C(x-x_0)} \mathbb 1(x > x_0) \, dx = C \int_{x=x_0}^\infty x^k e^{-C(x-x_0)} \, dx.$$  (And yes, my choice of notation is very slightly different.)  The point is that using an indicator function allows you to formalize the support of the distribution, and carry that over into your calculations.  Now to finish evaluating the integral, you would do a substitution...which is tantamount to the same transformation that we discussed above.

Comment: Wow. Does it mean that my result was wrong ?

Comment: Yes.  Right away, you can see that your calculation of the variance cannot be correct, because the variance should not be a function of the location parameter.  The effect of translating the support of the distribution by $x_0$ does not affect its spread.  That is to say,  $$\operatorname{Var}[X-x_0] = \operatorname{Var}[X]$$ for any constant $x_0$ and any random variable $X$ with finite variance

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your input. I will be also following what Did suggested so that I can get both approaches. Thanks again for your help. Just one side question: would it have been a good idea to do a change of variable with $u=X-x0$ only (without the $C$) ? that's where I started initially.

Comment: Yes, you can also just do a transformation to remove the location parameter, but then the calculation of the expectation and variance is slightly more complicated owing to the presence of the rate parameter $C$.  However, if you recognize that such a transformation gives you an exponential distribution with rate parameter $C$, and recall that such a distribution has mean $1/C$ and variance $1/C^2$, then the result also follows.  (Note that $C$ is technically a rate parameter, being the reciprocal of a scale parameter).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought during the calculation: $E(X)=\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ Cx{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }{ 1 }_{ x>{ x }_{ 0 } } } dx=\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ C(u+{ x }_{ 0 }){ e }^{ -Cu }du } =\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ u{ Ce }^{ -Cu }du } +{ x }_{ 0 }\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ { Ce }^{ -Cu }du } =1/C+{ x }_{ 0 }$ This is what I tried at the very beginning. Because $\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ { Ce }^{ -Cu }du } =1$ and $\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ u{ Ce }^{ -Cu }du } $ is a regular exponential for which E(X) et V(X) are easy.

Comment: But your change of variable is more brilliant than mine :-). Thanks a lot for your time. By the way, can you look up on what Did suggested to me please ? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: By following another approach (the Gamma approach), I'm finding something weird: $E(X)=\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ Cx{ e }^{ -C(x-{ x }_{ 0 }) }{ 1 }_{ x>{ x }_{ 0 } } } dx=C{ e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } }\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ x{ e }^{ -Cx }{ 1 }_{ x>0 } } dx=C{ e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } }\frac { 1! }{ { C }^{ 2 } } \int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ \frac { { C }^{ 2 } }{ 1! } x{ e }^{ -Cx }{ 1 }_{ x>0 } } dx=\frac { { e }^{ C{ x }_{ 0 } } }{ C } $ Why do I get this wrong result ?